# Arrows keys for getch in python

Tags: python, linux, arrow-keys, getch

I want to capture arrow keys in python linux:

```
   import getch as gh
   ch = ''
   while ch != 'q':
       print(ch)
       ch = gh.getch()
       k = ord(ch)
       print(k)
       # my question is:
       if k or ch = ???
          print("up")
```

When I run the code above and hit arrow keys, I get the following chars, what are they and how can I match one?

```
27

1
[
66
B
27

1
[
67
C
27

1
[
65
A
```

Comment: [Refer to this Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right)

Comment: @PalakodetiSaiVinay that is for C, it's for python. For every language and even the package the solution differ....

Comment: @Ahmad A lot of Python API is just a wrapper for C API.  If you are given a reference to C API it's best to check if Python wraps it.  Check if python behaves the same.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I searched for a solution with python and found no straightforward and workable one. I think this could be a common question and deserve such an answer! many can't read many technical things to figure out a solution for such a common question!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked question for C, and should not have been marked as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

When we execute the code below in a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator):

```py
import getch as gh

ch = ''
while ch != 'q':
    ch = gh.getch()
    print(ord(ch))
```

it prints the following when we hit the arrow up <kbd>↑</kbd> key once:

```
27
91
65
```

Referring [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/), we can see that it corresponds to `ESC[A`. It is the code for "[Cursor UP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CUU)" in ANSI escape sequences. (The sequence for [CSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI) is `ESC [`, so `ESC[A` == `CSI A` == `CSI 1 A` which means "Moves the cursor one cell in the up direction.")

In the same way, we can figure out the other arrow keys also.

---

If you want to match arrow keys by using the [getch module](https://pypi.org/project/getch/), you can try the following code (`get_key` function below is originally from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378376/8581025)):

```py
import getch as gh


# The function below is originally from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378376/8581025
def get_key():
    first_char = gh.getch()
    if first_char == '\x1b':
        return {'[A': 'up', '[B': 'down', '[C': 'right', '[D': 'left'}[gh.getch() + gh.getch()]
    else:
        return first_char


key = ''
while key != 'q':
    key = get_key()
    print(key)
```

which prints the following when we press <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>

```
up
down
left
right
q
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant as straightforward workable solution, which has no duplicate!